# Возможно ли установить "красиво" несколько обратчиков событий на элемент?

Tags: javascript

Нужно установить несколько обработчиков события на элемент(клик, нажатия клавиши). Ниже код с примером.

Пример:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert('А я сработало..') 
}, false);
window.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
      alert('А я сработало..') 
}, false);
```

Но возможно есть какой-то красивый вариант записи кода. К примеру, чтоб обработчики можно было перечислить в строку(без jQuery) ?

Comment: всегда можно написать свою функцию

Comment: @Grundy, стандартных возможностей для такой записи в js нет ?

Comment: Если бы были, то jQuery был бы не нужен :)

Comment: А в jQuery изи на самом деле реализовать такое.

Comment: @Grundy, что-то всё больше разработчиков от него (jquery) отказываються. Не пойму почему... Удобная штука)

Comment: @Kiril1995, очень много уже можно реализовать нативно, поэтому в некоторых случаях нет смысла тащить всю библиотеку.

Comment: @EugenEray, в jQuery это _уже_ реализовано

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В функцию [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) первым параметром передается *конкретный* тип события. Передача списка не поддерживается ни в каком виде: ни в строке через разделитель, ни в массиве.

Всегда можно сделать свою функцию, которая будет сама проходить по переданным типам событий и вызывать *addEventListener*, например:

```
registerHandler(target, types, handler){
    types.split(' ').forEach(type=> target.addEventListener(type, handler, false));
}
```

данную функцию можно вызвать следующим образом

```
registerHandler(window, 'click keypress', function() {
  console.log('А я сработало..');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, отличный способ

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать как то так:

```js
['click', 'keypress', 'resize', 'scroll'].forEach(event =>
  window.addEventListener(event, function() {
    alert('А я сработало..')
  }, false)
);
```